Getting exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest
package SelAuto;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class GetTitleandURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ar-in-u-262/Eclipse/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://games.pragmaticplaylive.net/authentication/authenticate.jsp");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.close();
    }
}

Error is below-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest (in module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http) cannot access class dev.failsafe.function.CheckedFunction (in unnamed module @0x78b729e6) because module org.seleniumhq.selenium.http does not read unnamed module @0x78b729e6
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.\<clinit\>(RetryRequest.java:39)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.\<clinit\>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.\<init\>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.\<init\>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at Introduction/SelAuto.GetTitleandURL.main(GetTitleandURL.java:13)

I added jar files under classpath instead of module path . But it did not work .
